# Is it possible to pause a game across restarts?

Tags: technical-issues, fifa-13

I'll get right to the point, i'm having savegame issues in FIFA 13 Career Mode on Windows 10.

There's my most recent save (let's call is "Save A") which loads fine, but if i play a few matches in the Career Mode and then save the game into a new file other than "Save A", i cannot load from the most recent save. The game instead crashes upon loading the game.

So basically, i can only load the game from "Save A" and any future savegames beyong "Save A" onward would simply crash the game.

Now, i was wondering, instead of relying on FIFA's ingame save feature, what if i could just somehow pause/suspend the game process (FIFA13.exe) when i am done playing for a particular time. Then i shutdown my laptop. And when i return to play the game again, i just boot up my laptop, resume the suspended FIFA13.exe and start off where i left from without the need to ever use the save game feature ?

is such a facility possible in Windows 10 ?

Since this is a gaming forum, i'd like to go one step ahead and express my gaming sentiments. I am a die-hard fan of the career mode, it's pretty much the only mode i play in the FIFA series and right now i don't have a powerful PC which means i cant play the most recent FIFA iterations. so i am content with playing the old version for the time being. i really enjoy taking a team from lower divisions and rebuilding it from the very base and eventually taking the team to inter-continental and global glory, discovering brilliant young players in the game and so on...

i would be absolutely gutted to lose my progress in the game, which is why i have resorted to asking the community on this forum to help me out.

P.S : i posted more details on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FIFA/comments/79uy8k/fifa_13_career_mode_crashfreeze/), please be kind enough and check them out.

i would be grateful if anyone can help resolve this issue.